Kafka Kraft setup on Kubernetes minikube with Python Producer and Consumer
I'm trying to connect to the Kubernetes Minikube Kafka pod from outside the Kubernetes cluster.
The server starts without any problem, but I can't manage to connect a local Kafka producer or consumer to the external Kafka pod.
On the Kafka server image inside the cluster I set the bootstrap-server as:
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic "test"
The service for the Kafka server pod is set as:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      port: 9092
      nodePort: 30092
  selector:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}

The only Kafka config that I set in the deployment are below for the listeners.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-deployment
  labels:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.deployment.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.deployment.image }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.deployment.pullPolicy }}
          command: {{ .Values.deployment.initCommand | toYaml | nindent 12 }}
          ports:
              - containerPort: 9092
                name: internal
              - containerPort: 9093
                name: controller
              - containerPort: 30092
                name: nodeport
          env:
            - name: KRAFT_TOPIC_ML
              value: {{ .Values.deployment.topic.nameML }}
            - name: KRAFT_TOPIC_ML_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "{{ .Values.deployment.topic.replicationFactorML }}"
            - name: KRAFT_TOPIC_ML_PARTITIONS
              value: "{{ .Values.deployment.topic.partitionsML }}"
            - name: KRAFT_TOPIC_MILP
              value: {{ .Values.deployment.topic.nameMILP }}
            - name: KRAFT_TOPIC_MILP_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "{{ .Values.deployment.topic.replicationFactorMILP }}"
            - name: KRAFT_TOPIC_MILP_PARTITIONS
              value: "{{ .Values.deployment.topic.partitionsMILP }}"

            - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
              value: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,NODEPORT:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL"
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
              value: "INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,NODEPORT://0.0.0.0:30092,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093"
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: "INTERNAL://localhost:9092,NODEPORT://localhost:30092"
            - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
              value: "INTERNAL"
            - name: KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER
              value: "CONTROLLER"

When trying to connect to the Kafka server locally on my machine with the local IP and PORT as 30092, I can find the broker and connect, but when producing messages, it doesn't show up on the consumer Python side on the same IP and PORT.
I tried changing the Kafka listeners config without any success.

The port in the service should also be 30092. I recommend you try Strimzi rather than writing your own Helm Charts
